# how to apply array operations on an object array?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Given the new [object type](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Objects.html#:%7E:text=Pine%20Script%E2%84%A2%20objects%20are,of%20UDTs%20as%20methodless%20classes.) that is introduced in PS.
I was wondering how I can apply array operations on the objects with array type?

given

```
// Define the `pivotPoint` UDT containing the time and price of pivots.
type pivotPoint
    int openTime
    float lowValue

// Create an empty `pivotPoint` array.
var MyArray = array.new<pivotPoint>()
```

is there any way to sort the `MyArray` based on `lowValue` or  get them `min` results in terms of the `lowValue`s ? etc...

Not sure if the object type still incomplete or it will get more complete and advance, but super excited about it!

Comment: For your use case a matrix is still more appropriate. Much more flexible, with native solutions, like matrix.sort()

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it easily just yet.

As a workaround, I've written a function that sorts the objects in a given array. It's not perfect, and defiantly not scalable since you need to know in advance the field type and field name, and hardcode it to the function, but it might be enough for your needs:

```
sort(_array, _order = order.ascending) => 
    lowValueArray = array.new_float()

    for element in _array
        array.push(lowValueArray, element.lowValue)

    lowValueArrayCopy = array.copy(lowValueArray)
    array.sort(lowValueArray, _order)

    newArray = array.copy(_array)

    for i=0 to array.size(lowValueArray) - 1
        originalIndex = array.indexof(lowValueArrayCopy, array.get(lowValueArray, i))
        originalElement = array.get(_array, originalIndex)
        array.set(newArray, i, originalElement)

    newArray
```

The function basically creates a copy of the original array, and populate the new array according to the sorted values. You can use it for example like this:

```
sortedMyArray = sort(MyArray)
```

Now `sortedMyArray` is an `array` of sorted objects in ascending order of `lowValue`.

You can apply same logic in order to get the `min` and `max` values.